# Make a slider from the reviews block

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, review, slider

I moved the reviews from the tab block

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <container name="product-review-container" as="product-review-container" after="main.content">
        <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_additional_data" template="product/view/list.phtml"/>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

and deleted the tab because I don't need him

```
<referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true"/>
```

[image]

**question:** how to create a slider with reviews from the reviews block

more or less like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download owl carousal from [OwlCarousal](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)
And paste owl.carousel.js to `app/design/frontend/Ctm/customtheme/web/js/owl.carousel.js`

owl.carousel.min.css to `app/design/frontend/Ctm/customtheme/web/css/owl.carousel.min.css`

Create requirejs-config.js with below code in `app/design/frontend/Ctm/customtheme/Magento_Theme/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'owlcarousel': "js/owl.carousel"
    }
};
```

Enqueue css using `app/design/frontend/Ctm/customtheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/owl.carousel.min.css" media="all"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Finally call the owl slider from list.phtml file. Override from `vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/product/view/list.phtml` to 
`app/design/frontend/Ctm/customtheme/Magento_Review/templates/product/view/list.phtml` with below code

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView $block */

$_items = $block->getReviewsCollection()->getItems();
$format = $block->getDateFormat() ?: \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT;
?>
<?php if (count($_items)):?>
<div class="block review-list" id="customer-reviews">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Customer Reviews')) ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <div class="toolbar review-toolbar">
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('toolbar') ?>
        </div>
        <ol class="owl-carousel items review-items">
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_review):?>
            <li class="item review-item" itemscope itemprop="review" itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
                <div class="review-title" itemprop="name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_review->getTitle()) ?></div>
                <?php if (count($_review->getRatingVotes())): ?>
                    <div class="review-ratings">
                    <?php foreach ($_review->getRatingVotes() as $_vote): ?>
                    <div class="rating-summary item" itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
                        <span class="label rating-label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($_vote->getRatingCode()) ?></span></span>
                        <div class="rating-result" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_vote->getPercent()) ?>%">
                            <meta itemprop="worstRating" content = "1"/>
                            <meta itemprop="bestRating" content = "100"/>
                            <span style="width:<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_vote->getPercent()) ?>%">
                                <span itemprop="ratingValue"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_vote->getPercent()) ?>%</span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="review-content" itemprop="description">
                    <?= nl2br($block->escapeHtml($_review->getDetail())) ?>
                </div>
                <div class="review-details">
                    <p class="review-author">
                        <span class="review-details-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Review by')) ?></span>
                        <strong class="review-details-value" itemprop="author"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_review->getNickname()) ?></strong>
                    </p>
                    <p class="review-date">
                        <span class="review-details-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Posted on')) ?></span>
                        <time class="review-details-value" itemprop="datePublished" datetime="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt(), $format)) ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt(), $format)) ?></time>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
        <div class="toolbar review-toolbar">
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('toolbar') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'owlcarousel'
        ], function () {
            'use strict';
            jQuery.noConflict();
            jQuery(".items.review-items").owlCarousel({
                autoPlay: 3000, //3000 Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
                margin:5,
                items : 2,
                itemsDesktop : [1199,2],
                itemsDesktopSmall : [979,2],
                itemsTablet : [768,2],
                nav : true,
                pagination : false
          });
    });
</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: if I make changes not in the module, but in the topic, then where to put the files?

Comment: Do you have custom theme?

Comment: yes app/design/frontend/Ctm/customtheme

Comment: Updated my answer